# Hadoop WordCount for multiple words not getting the public variables

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a simple Hadoop program that I need to implement for an essay in mu University.
It's an alternative WordCount problem, It should make combined Text() strings that have n words and to sum up with the reducer only the ones that are >= than k appearances.
I have put the n and k integers to get caught from the command line after the input and output folders (args[3] and args[4]).
The issue is that n and k when they are used inside the mapper and the reducer are empty, despite the fact that get their values correctly from the command.
The code is the below, what goes wrong?

```
public class MultiWordCount {

    public static int n;
    public static int k;

public static class TokenizerMapper
        extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    private StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                if (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    phrase.append(itr.nextToken());
                    phrase.append(" ");

                }
            }
            word.set(phrase.toString());
            context.write(word, one);
            phrase.setLength(0);
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer
        extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        if(sum >= k) {
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 n = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
 k = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "multi word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your Java-based logic here looks sound, Map and Reduce function implemented functions in Hadoop are more myopic or independent than one thinks. To be more precise, you declare public static variables in the parent class and initialize them in the driver/main function, but the mapper/reducer instances do not have any access to the driver, but only to their strict scopes within the `TokenizerMapper` and `IntSumReducer` classes. This is why `n` and `k` seem empty when you look inside the mappers and reducers.

Since your program has only one job and is executed within a single Hadoop `Configuration`, no [Hadoop Counters](https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-counters/) are needed here. You can just declare `Configuration` based values that will be accessed by every mapper and reducer right before the executions of the Map and Reduce functions, through the `setup` functions inside the `TokenizerMapper` and `IntSumReducer` classes.

To declare those types of values in order to pass them to the MapReduce functions, you can just do something like this in the driver/main method:

`conf.set("n", args[2]);`

And then access this value (while converting it fron `String` to `int`) in the `setup` methods of `TokenizerMapper` and `IntSumReducer`:

`n = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("n"));`

So the program can look like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counters;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class MultiWordCount 
{
    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        private StringBuilder phrase = new StringBuilder();
        private int n;

        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            n = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("n"));
        }

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) 
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                {
                    if (itr.hasMoreTokens()) 
                    {
                        phrase.append(itr.nextToken());
                        phrase.append(" ");

                    }
                }

                word.set(phrase.toString());
                context.write(word, one);
                phrase.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> 
    {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
        private int k;

        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            k = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("k"));
        }

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) 
                sum += val.get();

            if(sum >= k) 
            {
                result.set(sum);
                context.write(key, result);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set("n", args[2]);
        conf.set("k", args[3]);

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(new Path(args[1])))
            fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Multi Word Count");
        job.setJarByClass(MultiWordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

And for `n=3` and `k=1`, the output looks like this (using a number of text files with Franz Kafka sentences as seen [here](https://github.com/Coursal/Hadoop-Letter-File-Index-Counter/tree/master/input)):

[image]

Comment: Great, really appreciated

Comment: What if I want to check the input as case-insensitive and without punctuation marks?

Comment: ok I have changed all line .toLowerCase() and also .replaceAll() to remove the punctuation.