# Why List<String> is always empty when using MapReduce and HDFS?

Tags: java, docker, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

So I have a program that it uses **Mapper**, **Combiner** and **Reducer** to get some fields of the IMDB repository and this program fine works when I'm running it on my machine.

When I put this code to run inside **Docker** using **Hadoop HDFS** it doesn't get some values that I need, or to be precise, the **Combiner** which puts some values into a **List**, that is a **public class variable**, doesn't work or something because when I try to use that **List** in the **Reducer** it looks like it is always empty. When I was running on my machine (without **Docker** and **Hadoop HDFS**) it would put the values into the **List** but when running on **Docker** it looks like it is always empty. I have also printed the size of the **List** on the main and it returns 0, any suggestions?

```
public class FromParquetToParquetFile{

    public static List<String> top10 = new ArrayList<>();
    ....
}
```

The **Combiner** looks like:

```
public static class FromParquetQueriesCombiner extends Reducer<Text,Text, Text,Text> {

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            long total = 0;
            long maior = -1;
            String tconst = "";
            String title = "";

            for (Text value : values) {

                total++; //numero de filmes
                String[] fields = value.toString().split("\t");
                top10.add(key.toString() + "\t" + fields[2] + "\t" + fields[3] + "\t" + fields[0] + "\t" + fields[1]);
                int x = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);

                if (x >= maior) {
                    tconst = fields[0]; 
                    title = fields[1]; 
                    maior = x;
                }
            }

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.append(total);
            result.append("\t");
            result.append(tconst);
            result.append("\t");
            result.append(title);
            result.append("\t");
            context.write(key, new Text(result.toString()));
        }
    }
```

And Reducer looks like (it has a setup to order the List):

```
public static class FromParquetQueriesReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Void, GenericRecord> {
        private Schema schema;

        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Collections.sort(top10, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    String[] aux = o1.split("\t");
                    String[] aux2 = o2.split("\t");

                    ...
                    return -result;
                }
            });
            schema = getSchema("hdfs:///schema.alinea2");
        }

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         
           ...
           for(String s : top10)
           ...
           }
      }
```

Comment: Does that list of Strings have relatively small Strings in each element? I'm asking this because this is crucial memory-wise for the safe execution of the MR job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919093/5644037), "public" variables (in Java sense) don't quite "translate" into a parallel computing model aimed to be implemented in a distributed system (and this is why while you didn't have any issue running your application locally, things "broke" when you run it along the HDFS).

Mapper and Reducer instances are isolated and more-or-less "independent" from whatever being put "around" the functions that describe them. That means they don't really have access to the variables being put either on the parent class (i.e. `FromParquetToParquetFile` here) or in the driver/main function of the program. From that we can understand that (in case you want to preserve the current way of functionality your job has) we need some type of risky workaround (or a straight up hack job) to make a list publicly accessible and "static" within the thematic constraints we are working on.

The solution for this is to set user-named values that are referring to the job's [Configuration](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) object. This means that you have to use the `Configuration` object you probably created in your driver to set `top10` as this type of variable. Since your `List` *may* have relatively "small" `Strings` in length (i.e. just several sentences) for each element, all you have to do is use some sort of a delimiter to store all of the elements in just one `String` (since this is the datatype used for those type of `Configuration` variables) like this **`element1#element2#element3#...`** (***but*** *be **very** careful with this, as you must **always** be sure that there's enough memory for that `String` to exist in the first place*, this is why this is merely a **workaround** after all).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    conf.set("top10", " ");    // initialize `top10` as an empty String

    // the description of the job(s), etc, ...
}
```

In order to read and write to `top10`, at first you need to declare it to the `setup` function that you need to have in both of your combiner and your reducer like this (with the code snippet below showing how it would look like for the reducer, of course):

```
public static class FromParquetQueriesReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Void, GenericRecord> 
{
    private Schema schema;
    private String top10;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    {
        top10 = context.getConfiguration().get("top10");

        // everything else inside the setup function...
    }

    // ...
}
```

With those two adjustments, you can use `top10` inside the `reduce` function of yours just fine, after using the `split` function to split the elements from inside the `String` of `top10` like this:

```
String[] data = top10.split("#");           // split the elements from the String
List<String> top10List = new ArrayList<>(); // create ArrayList 
Collections.addAll(top10List, data);        // put all the elements to the list
```

With all that being said, I must say that this type of functionality is way beyond the abilities of vanilla Hadoop that heavily relies on MapReduce. In case this is anything more than a CS class assignment, you need to reevaluate the usage of Hadoop's MapReduce engine here, in order to make out of all of this with "extensions" like [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) or [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) that are way more flexible and SQL-like and can match some of the aspects of your application.